Is there a way to use CodeBERT to embed source code without natural language in input?
On CodeBERTS github they provide an example of using a NL-PL pair with the pretrained base model to  create an embedding. I am looking to create an embedding using just source code which does not have natural language attached. This will be so that I can try and use cosine similarity to find similarity from one source code embedding to another. Would it be less desirable to simply remove the natural language tokens as opposed to another method?
In this source code I recreated the suggested embedding method but without any natural language tokens. My final similarity results were not exceptional so I cannot confirm if this was the best method or not.
>>> from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
>>> import torch
>>> tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/codebert-base")
>>> model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/codebert-base")
>>> code_tokens=tokenizer.tokenize("def max(a,b): if a>b: return a else return b")
['def', 'Ġmax', '(', 'a', ',', 'b', '):', 'Ġif', 'Ġa', '>', 'b', ':', 'Ġreturn', 'Ġa', 'Ġelse', 'Ġreturn', 'Ġb']
>>> tokens=[tokenizer.cls_token]+[tokenizer.sep_token]+code_tokens+[tokenizer.eos_token]
['<s>', '</s>', 'def', 'Ġmax', '(', 'a', ',', 'b', '):', 'Ġif', 'Ġa', '>', 'b', ':', 'Ġreturn', 'Ġa', 'Ġelse', 'Ġreturn', 'Ġb', '</s>']
>>> tokens_ids=tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
[0, 2, 9232, 19220, 1640, 102, 6, 428, 3256, 114, 10, 15698, 428, 35, 671, 10, 1493, 671, 741, 2]
>>> context_embeddings=model(torch.tensor(tokens_ids)[None,:])[0]
torch.Size([1, 20, 768])
tensor([[-0.1423,  0.3766,  0.0443,  ..., -0.2513, -0.3099,  0.3183],
        ...,
        [-0.1433,  0.3785,  0.0450,  ..., -0.2527, -0.3121,  0.3207]],
       grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)

I also noticed the project https://github.com/neulab/code-bert-score which seeks to accomplish something similar as they make nl an optional input. However, I was unable to unobscure the exact method of completing this task from their utils.
